# Redirect user by geo ip but not googlebot

Tags: php, redirect, geolocation, seo, googlebot

we have two website one for EU users and the other only for users in USA.

I use a simple system that checks the origin of the IP.

```
  $geo = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/$user_ip"));
  $country = $geo->countryCode;
  $countrycode = $sanitizer->pageName(substr($country, 0, 2));
```

After which, based on the response, I redirect the user to the correct site.

```
if ($countrycode == 'us'){
    // go to usa website 
}else{
   // do nothing 
}
```

Now, the problem is that Google came from USA, and I need to not redirect the googlebot (and other bot) in the way that it can scan the EU site which is the main one.

I looking a lot on internet and finally I did this:

```
if( strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot") )  {
        $countrycode = 'en'; // force him to have en instead of us
    }
```

Now, I'm not very happy about this, Googlebot scan my website but I'm not sure if work really well. Because google speed test see only the USA website. 
I'm afraid that isn't the best way to deal with this problem.

Do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide from Google

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

My recommendation would be to implement href-lang and have seperated URLs for every language version

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077

I would just redirect the homepage with a 302 redirect to the corresponding language version

so

example.com > 302 > example.com/us if you are in US
example.com > 302 > example.com/uk if you are in UK

and both of them connected with href-lang referring to the other version. Google will list

example.com/us in US

and

example.com/uk in UK

like this as the homepage. Do the same for all subpage, thus Google will just list /uk/ pages in UK. With this method you don't have to care about Googlebot. In theory its possible to show Googlebot something different buts it's risky because they not just use one Googlebot.